# Custom Post Type and API REST is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have been created a custom post type called 'customers'. I'm registering step by step as documentation says. But when I call to rest api, It just return a 404 response. See the code below:

```
add_action('init', 'customer_post_type');
function customer_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x('Customers', 'customers'),
        'singular_name'       => _x('Customer', 'customers'),
        'menu_name'           => __('Customers', 'customers'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __('Parent Customer', 'customers'),
        'all_items'           => __('All Customers', 'customers'),
        'view_item'           => __('View Customer', 'customers'),
        'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Customer', 'customers'),
        'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'customers'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit Customer', 'customers'),
        'update_item'         => __('Update Customer', 'customers'),
        'search_items'        => __('Search Customer', 'customers'),
        'not_found'           => __('Not Found', 'customers'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __('Not found in Trash', 'customers'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __('Customers', 'customers'),
        'description'         => __('Customer news and reviews', 'customers'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => false,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-desktop',
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'rest_base'           => 'customer',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Post_Controller'
    );

    register_post_type('customers', $args);
}
```

the urls that I testing for, are: `/wp-json/wp/v2/customers` and `/wp-json/wp/v2/customer`

Comment: Why is 'has_archive' set to false?

Comment: I would play around with a couple of those false values and while I don't know what they do, I don't typically include `'rest_base'` or `'rest_controller_class'`

Comment: @git-e-up There are set in their own default values, but error still happening if I remove it

Comment: By remove it you mean set to true?

Comment: Not, just removing it

Comment: I would try and set everything you have as false to true and then go back and make changes if need be (and also remove the 'rest_base' and 'rest_controller_class' for now)

Comment: Yeah now it works well, I removed 'rest_base', 'rest_controller' and 'has_archive' fields @git-e-up if you want to write your answer

Answer (score -1):

Something I had to do, was instead of making it "restable" when i register the post type, I did it later.

like this.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type_rest_support', 25 );

function my_custom_post_type_rest_support() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    //be sure to set this to the name of your post type!
    $post_type_name_customers = 'customer';
    if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name_customers ] ) ) {
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name_customers]->show_in_rest = true;
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name_customers]->rest_base = $post_type_name_customers;
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name_customers]->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
    }
}
```

Like this, I was able to get my CPT through rest.

You could try it out -

Remember to remove them from the registration of the post form.

Also, you might have to set `"public" => true` But i am not sure.